# Upper bound for $\mathbb{E}[1/(1+M)]$, where $M$ follows Binomial distribution $B(n,p)$

Tags: probability, inequality

Since $\frac{1}{1+M}$ is convex, it's easy to get $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{1+M}] \ge \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[M]+1} = \frac{1}{np+1}$. However, what I need is one simply upper bound in terms of $n^{-1}$. Any good idea? Upper bound in the case that $n$ is big enough is also ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Heuristics

You may play with different values of $n$ in [my online graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wqhvwgkeu0).  (I have changed $p$ to $x$ for technical reasons, replaced $n$ with $10^n$ (injective function on $n$), and $\log$ preserves boundedness on $p\in(0,1)$).  The $y$-intercept of the strictly decreasing convex curve is *observed* to be the value of $n$ that you've set.

## Motivation (*edited in response to comments*)

Based on [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2558264/290189), $$\bbox[2px, border: 1px solid black]{\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{1+M}\right] =\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot\frac{1-(1-p)^{n+1}}{p}} \color{gray}{\left(\le\frac{1}{(n+1)p}\right)}.$$
If $p$ becomes $\text{s}\small\text{ma}\tiny\text{ll}$, then $\left((n+1)\tiny{p}\right)^{\Large{-1}} \large\text{blows } \Large\text{up}$.  Since OP asks for an upper bound in terms to $n$, I'll try to get rid of $p$ *by taking supremum on $p\in(0,1)$*.  By doing so, we will see eventually that the upper bound is $1$.  *From the first comment, you will see that this is immediate from monotonicity of $\Bbb E$.  However, by doing so, you will know that **the best upper bound for $\Bbb {E}[1/(1+M)]$ independent of $p$ is $1$***.

## Formal derivation

From the graph, we see that the key step is to establish *monotone* convergence $(1-(1-p)^{n+1})/p \uparrow n$ as $p \downarrow 0$ for each *fixed* $n$.  (Monotonicity allows us to put an inequality sign without considering $\epsilon$-$\delta$.)

To get rid of $p$, for each *fixed* $n$, define
\begin{align}
f_n(p)&=\frac{1-(1-p)^{n+1}}{p} \quad \forall\,p\in(0,1). \\
f_n'(p)&=\frac{(n+1)p(1-p)^n-(1-(1-p)^{n+1})}{p^2} \\
&= \frac{[(n+1)p+(1-p)](1-p)^n-1}{p^2} \\
&= \frac{(np+1)(1-p)^n-1}{p^2} < 0
\end{align}

The last inequality is due to the fact that [the range of $g_{jn} (x) =(1+jx)(1-x)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1929123/290189) is $[0,1]$.  In the answer of that question, $g_{jn} '(x) < 0$, so $g_{jn} (x)$ is injective.  In this case, take $j=n$ and $x=p$.  Since we suppose that $p \in (0,1)$, we can take away the the endpoints $0$ and $1$ from the range and conclude that $0<g_{nn}(p)=f_n(p)<1$ for all $p \in (0,1)$.

To evaluate the limit of $f_n(p)$ as $p\downarrow0$, we expand the first few terms of the denominator.  The terms with degree $\ge2$ with respect to $p$ vanish as $p\downarrow0$, leaving $n+1$ alone.

$$\bbox[2px, border: 1px solid black]{f_n(p) \le \frac{1-(1-p)^{n+1}}{p} \le n+1}$$

Combining this with another answer, we have $$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{1+M}\right] \le 1.$$
**No better upper bound *independent of $p$* exists.**

Comment: There was no need to do all this stuff.  You know $M\geq 0$ almost surely, hence by monotonicity $E[(1+M)^{-1}] \leq E[1]=1$.

Comment: @Shashi You are right.  Thinking about independence from $p$, I forgot this fact.

Comment: @Shashi I remember why I wrote this answer.  I was thinking how to improve the suggested upper bound $\frac{1}{(n+1)p}$.  (say, something of $O(1/n^2)$)  By taking $\sup$ over $p\in(0,1)$, you'll know that that's impossible.

Comment: Yes I was also trying to do so, until someone commented on the question that the upper bound was the best upper bound one can get. Was that you?

Comment: @Shashi Yes, but I deleted this since I think it's not quite right.  Your comment on another answer would be the best.  Lemme edit my answer to address to your first comment.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306901/find-the-expected-value-of-frac1x1-where-x-is-binomial), $\mathbb{E}(\frac{1}{1+M}) =\frac{1}{(n+1)p}\cdot(1-(1-p)^{n+1})$, the upper bound can be $\frac{1}{(n+1)p}$.

Comment: +1 for the link to another answer.  As OP asks for an upper bound in terms of $n$, see my answer for an upper bound *independent* of $p$.

Comment: I would say $E[(1+M)^{-1}]\leq \min\{1, ((n+1)p)^{-1}\}$.